# Raphael.js - Run function after animation, while passing parameters

Tags: javascript, raphael

```
test(0);

function test(Num){ 
    if (Num<6){
        ball.attr({ cy:520 , cx:900});
        ball.animate({cy: 520 , cx: 400}, speed, test(Num+1));  
    }else{
        //something
    }           
}
```

I have this code written using the Raphael Javascript framework but cannot get it to callback. Specifically the test(Num+1), how do I pass the parameter back so the function will repeat x times as currently it just runs once and stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to bind an parameter to the callback function. Rather than executing the callback function (unless it returns a function itself).

For example, try

```
test.bind(null,Num+1)
```

for the callback function instead of test(Num+1).